# How to use jQuery/Javascript to change <tr> attribute in gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

I have a nested GridView and I set `<tr style="display:none">` to display only the main GridView `gvPosition`. what I want to do is that once user clicks the Label `lblPosition`, then change the display attribute to "initial" then it will show the second GridView `gvInput` that contains text boxes to input something.

I am pretty new to jQuery and Javascript, I need some help!

Thank you very much!

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvPosition"
        DataKeyNames="Position" EmptyDataText="No Data Returned" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvPosition_RowDataBound" SkinID="Grid">
        <Columns> 
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Position">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblPosition" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Position")%>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>            
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Surplus" HeaderText="Surplus" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Total Credits" HeaderText="Total Credits" />

            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnEdit" Text="Edit" CssClass="btn btn-primary" CommandName="EditButton" CommandArgument="<%# ((GridViewRow) Container).RowIndex %>" />
                    <tr style="display:none">
                        <td></td>
                        <td colspan="100">
                            <asp:Panel ID="pnlInputs" runat="server">
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvInput" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" SkinID="Grid">
                                    <Columns>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PCredit: ">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:TextBox ID="tbPC" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PCredit") %>' CssClass="form-control" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>

                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Heads: ">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="tbHeads" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("BA") %>' CssClass="form-control" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </asp:Panel>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>

        <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />

    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#lblPosition').click(function() {
    $('tr').css('display', 'initial');
});
```

Though I suggest adding a class to your tr so as to not affect other tr which are not related. It would look like

```
$('#lblPosition').click(function() {
    $('.someclass').css('display', 'initial');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See this working example on changing the display style property.
[Link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_js)

TL;DR

```
  document.getElementById("some_id").style.display = "initial";
```

Comment: Please let us know if you need more help, if this worked for you select it as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can bind click event to call a JavaScript function by adding `onclick` attribute in page load function.

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    lblPosition.Attributes.Add("onclick", "btnEditClick();");
}
```

To refer to the `<td>` element, you should give it an ID. Let say:

```html
<tr id="tr" style="display:none">
```

Then you can have a JavaScript function that will restore the display style attribute of `<tr>` like so:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
     function btnEditClick()
     {
         var btn = document.getElementById('tr');
         btn.style.display = "";
         return false;
     }
</script>
```

If you prefer to set display to initial instead, you can do this:

```js
btn.style.display = "initial";
```

Comment: Thank you sir, this works, however, I tried ```btn.style.display = "initial"``` why this wouldn't work?

Comment: I wrote like this because I want to add an if statement, if style.display = "none" I will show the gridview, if it's 'initial' then close it

Comment: It might be the problem of browsers, chrome works fine, but not IE....

Comment: Yes, it seems like an IE issue. I think you can still do if statement without `initial`. You can check whether `btn.style.display` is `none` or not and set `btn.style.display = "";` or `btn.style.display = "none";` to show or hide.